# Telerik MVC tabstrip select tab with validation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

I created a form with a telerik tabstrip on it. The form is splitted over multiple tabs. When there is a validation error the current tab (even without a error) stays selected. Is it possible to select the first tab with an error on it.I have already:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myForm").submit(function () {
             var tabStrip = $('.t-widget.t-tabstrip.t-header').data('tTabStrip');
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

I can't figure out how to iterate trough the tabs and select the tab where the validation error is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    function gotoFirstError() {
        var $firstError = $('#myForm .input-validation-error').first();

        if ($firstError.size() === 1) {
            var id = $firstError.parents('.t-content').attr('id');

            var tabStrip = $("#TabStrip").data("tTabStrip");

            tabStrip.select($(".t-item", tabStrip.element)[parseInt(id.replace(/TabStrip-/, '')) - 1]);
        } else {
            console.log('no error found');
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        gotoFirstError();
    }, 0);

    $('#myForm').bind("invalid-form.validate", function () {
        $('#myForm').validate().showErrors();
        gotoFirstError();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Telerik had this example on the web site:

```
function SelectItem() {
    var tabStrip = $("#TabStrip").data("tTabStrip");

    tabStrip.select($(".t-item", tabStrip.element)[0]);
}
```

Other examples here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-tabstrip-client-api-and-events.html

HTH.

Comment: Hi Brian, I found that sample, but now how can I tell what tab has an error on it. That is my main problem.